# Naming list elements in R

Tags: r, list, names

I've been doing some work with some large, complex lists lately and I've seen some behaviour which was surprising (to me, at least), mainly to do with assigning names to a list. A simple example:

```
Fil <- list(
a = list(A=seq(1, 5, 1), B=rnorm(5), C=runif(5)), 
b = list(A="Cat", B=c("Dog", "Bird"), C=list("Squirrel", "Cheetah", "Lion")),
c = list(A=rep(TRUE, 5), B=rep(FALSE, 5), C=rep(NA, 5)))

filList <- list()

for(i in 1:3){
  filList[i] <- Fil[i]
  names(filList)[i] <- names(Fil[i])
}
identical(Fil,filList)
[1] TRUE
```

but:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  filList[i] <- Fil[i]
  names(filList[i]) <- names(Fil[i])
}
identical(Fil,filList)
[1] FALSE
```

I think the main reason it confuses me is because the form of the left-hand side of first `names` line in the first for loop needs to be different from that of the right-hand side to work; I would have thought that these should be the same. Could anybody please explain this to me?

Comment: I think of it like this, although the details are likely incorrect: when you run `names(filList[1])` you're essentially creating a new one element list within the environment created by the `names` function. Then you assign the new name, the function finishes running and your new list object is destroyed. However, when you run `names(filList)[1]` you are modifying the names of the `filList` object that exists in your global environment.

Comment: Btw, you can use the same form on both sides, like `names(x)[1] = names(y)[1]`

Comment: Thanks, dayne and Frank, for the explanations.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The first case is the correct usage. In the second case you are sending `filList[i]` to `names<-` which is only exists as a temporary subsetted object.

Alternatively, you could just do everything outside the loop with:

```
names(filList) <- names(Fil)
```

Comment: @dayne Yes, it is a separate copy which isn't bound to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

As @James pointed out, `names(filList)[i] <- ...` is the correct approach and `names(filList[i]) <- ...` does not work.

from `?names`:

> It is possible to update just part of the names attribute via the general rules: `names(z)[3] <- "c2"`. This works because the expression there is evaluated as `z <- "names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c3"))`.

```r
z <- list(a = 1, b = "c", c = 1:3)
names(z)[3] <- "c2"
z
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $c2
#> [1] 1 2 3

z <- "names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c3"))
z
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $c3
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

However, the reason that your second approach (`names(filList[i]) <-` ) does not work is NOT that "you create a unbound temporary variable whose names you change but which never matters since its just a temporary variable" but rather that the default sub-setting assignment operator `[<-` does not transfer names (which makes sense since `names` are `attributes` of the whole `SEXPREC` not the individual elements ). In R, `f(x[i])<- ...` is not necessarily the same as `tmp <- x[i]; f(tmp) <- ...`! In general, while R encourages functional programming, R functions (like `` `<-` ``) can do whatever they want with the calling environment and receive parameters not by reference or value but as expression.

We can override the subset-assign-operator to make it assign names as well:

```r
z <- list(a = 1, b = "c", c = 1:3)

names(z[2]) <- "b2" # does not work
z
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 1 2 3

`[<-` <- function(x, idx, value) {
  ret <- base::`[<-`(x, idx, value)
  names(ret) <- base::`[<-`(names(ret),idx, names(value))
  ret
}
names(z[2]) <- "b2" #does work
z
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b2
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 1 2 3
rm(`[<-`) # please don't use this in real life! At least, implement a S3 method (`[<-.yourclass`) instead
```

With that, both of your approaches would work.

Equipped with that knowledge you could also create a function to change just one name

```r
`name<-` <- function(x,i,value) {
  names(x)[i] <- value
  x # `function<-` functions return a modified version of their first argument which will be bound to the name of the first arguments symbol
}


name(z, 3) <- "c4"
z
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $c4
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>