# Why names(a[2])<- "e" not working, but names(a)[2]<-"e" is working in R Language

Tags: r

i tried Naming the Vector in R.
a<-1:5
names(a[2])<-"e"  #this is not showing any warning or error but Naming is not done

but

names(a)[2]<-"e" # this is is Naming the Element properly.

Kindly help with Explanation.

Comment: Similar to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643000/naming-list-elements-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643000/naming-list-elements-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

The basic difference is in understanding what a[1] and names(a)[1] stands for.

> a<-1:5 
>   (This assigns values 1 to 5 and creates a vector)
>
> a[1]   # This gives below output i.e the value stored at first location
>   [1] 1
>
> names(a)[1] # Shows the label associated with the value in this case 'NULL' yet

NULL

Now assigning the required name to the value

> names(a)[2]<-"e"

This does the correct assignment and is how the R expects the code. You can then extract the value by element name namely

> a["e"] #will give output
>   2